# Configuring Spring MVC with AngularJS-only HTML(no JSP's)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm struck with ajax call in AngularJS and Spring MVC.Please help me to resolve the problem.Thank you.

Spring-MVC Controller

```
@Controller
public class MasterController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  @ResponseBody String helloMsg() {           
    return "Hello";
}
}
```

Spring MVC mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
  <mvc:resources location="/static/**" mapping="/static/"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc.ng.controller"/>
```

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Welcome to home page</title>
  <script src="./static/lib/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/lib/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  <h2>{{message}}</h2>
  <h2>{{working}}</h2>
  <input ng-click="hello()" type="button" value="ajax">
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Angular App and Controller:

```
  var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
  myApp.controller("myController",["$scope",function($scope){
      $scope.name="XYZ";
      $scope.message="Hello";
      $scope.hello=function(){
          $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              dataType:'text',
              url:'/MVC-NG-Integration/hello',
              success:function(data){
                console.log('working');
              },
              error:function(error)
              {
                console.log(error);
              }
          });

      }
  }]);
```

Everything seems fine but when I make the ajax call it's returning-
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
"http://localhost:2016/MVC-NG-Integration/hello"
where am I going wrong?I haven't configured the viewResolver since I won't be using any JSP's.
I even used $http but no success.

Comment: From your spring controller it looks like the url should be **http://localhost:2016/hello** instead?

Comment: No,it isn't working.I think the problem is with view resolvers.configured them but no luck found!!